# how to change virtuemart 2 add to cart pop up text

Tags: popup, window, virtuemart

Basically as above,

I have a Virtuemart 2 online site with Add to Cart pop up enabled when it pops up all is well apart form the

View Cart and Continue Browsing links they have no separator in between them, I would like to have

View Cart | Continue Browsing

Ive looked at vmprices.js but have no clue :(

Can some one shed some light please?

Thank you!

Nick

Answer (score 1):

You have to look into these files to customize that popup:

```
com_virtuemart/controllers/cart.php

components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmprices.js
```

Thanks

Jafer Balti

Answer (score 0):

The actual text that is shown to the visitor is located in:

> mysite.com/languages/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini

Which can be changed, but should ideally be overridden.

This is harder to find than it should be because Dreamweaver does not search .ini files. Use the OS to search.

Additionally, the link for the "continue shopping" button can be changed by overriding the:

> components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/padded.php

file.